# how can select only true values from sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I select only true values from sqlserver? I wrote a query but when I test this query in sqlserver that returns all the fields but not true fields.

```
SELECT Fruit,Drink,Desert,MainFood,Salad,TableFlower,SaloonLighting,
Saloondesign,SloonCrew,Pastry,GiftCard 
FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes 
WHERE Fruit='True' and Drink='True'and Desert='True'and MainFood='True'and 
Salad='True'and TableFlower='True'and SaloonLighting='True'and 
Saloondesign='True'and SloonCrew='True'and Pastry='True' and GiftCard='True'
```

Comment: You should provide more info, at least clarify the meaning of "true values". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you post some test data and explain the expected result, it might be useful. Otherwise it's hard to realize what is your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On same row you cant.

But you can do ti:

```
   with distinctvalueyes (typearticle) as (
   select top 1 'Fruit' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Fruit=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'Drink' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Drink=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'Desert' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Desert=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'MainFood' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where MainFood=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'Salad' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Salad=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'TableFlower' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where TableFlower=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'SaloonLighting' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SaloonLighting=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'Saloondesign' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Saloondesign=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'SloonCrew' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SloonCrew=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'Pastry' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Pastry=1
   union all 
   select top 1 'GiftCard' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where GiftCard=1
   )
   select * from distinctvalueyes
```

Answer (score 0):

If yours fields type is BIT, you can do it:

```
SELECT Fruit,Drink,Desert,MainFood,Salad,TableFlower,SaloonLighting,
Saloondesign,SloonCrew,Pastry,GiftCard 
FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes 
WHERE Fruit=1 and Drink=1 and Desert=1 and MainFood=1 and 
Salad=1 and TableFlower=1 and SaloonLighting=1 and 
Saloondesign=1 and SloonCrew=1 and Pastry=1 and GiftCard=1
```

else can you explain what you want in output?

Comment: I want  to show me the fields that contains only True(1) values . but this Select query show me all fields.